# Percent in CSS selector name

Tags: css, css-selectors

What does this CSS selector mean?

```
50% {
..
}
```

Are there any references to this "trick"?

Comment: Never seen that before and no trace in W3C specs. Firebug says "Invalid selector" also. Are you sure about that? Can you give an online example?

Comment: Yes, i saw it https://daneden.me/animate/

Comment: You should have added more context. It would have been obvious that it wasn't a selector and what it was... This question looks like it was designed to be confusing.

Comment: Let's be fair, at first it edited by rink.attendant.6 user, so, really i didn't know about this syntax. At 3rd my english is not well..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a part of the `@keyframes` definition, that states "when the animation is 50% complete, these styles should be applied". Several such definitions produce an animation, and the values are interpolated according to the animation definition in another CSS rule.

A full CSS animation would look something like this:

```css
#flashy {animation: colourflash 5s linear infinite alternate}
@keyframes colourflash {
    from {background-color:red}
    50% {background-color:green}
    to {background-color:blue}
}
```

Comment: It is not a selector at all, and it is not called a selector in `@keyframes` drafts. It just confusingly looks like a selector.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela: I see many uses of the word "selector" here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#keyframes Apparently these things are called "keyframe selectors" (and the corresponding decl blocks, "keyframe decl blocks"), and apparently very intentionally so. They certainly aren't the same kinds of selectors that the Selectors module refers to, of course, since a percentage isn't a valid selector. But in retrospect, that's probably what you meant by "selector" anyway.